# JaCoCo report generation of functional tests for sonarqube

Tags: arrays, report, code-coverage, jacoco, sonar-runner

We are using Lisa functional test tool. I want to find out functional test coverage of tests. I have seen that we need to attach JaCoCo agent to JVM to generate report file. but I haven't understood how to generate it.

I have tried with IT coverage example given in sonarqube example folder. but my sonarqube dashboard doesn't show  integration test coverage.  I searched but not found detailed procedure. I have lot of confusion.

I will use sonar- runner to analyse project. please help

Comment: Corrected typo (JaCoCo instead of Jococo) + tagged jacoco & sonar

Comment: You might have to stop Tomcat (or the external JVM where the javaagent jacocoagent.jar is attached) so that it can flush the code coverage data to the destfile jacoco exec file. Then, you run jacoco test report from maven/gradle side and make sure in SonarQube, Integration Tests widget is enabled on the project's dashboard.